# Periodicity of cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $M$ a $\mathbb{Z} [G]$-module. Assume that given an sequence $$0\to M'\to F\to M\to 0 ,$$ where $F$ is a free $\mathbb{Z} [G]$-module and $M'={\rm Hom} (M,\mathbb{Z})$ is the dual of $M$, then $$\hat{H}^i(G,M)=\hat{H}^{i+1}(G,M')$$

Does it follow that $\hat{H}^{i+2}(G,M)=\hat{H}^{i}(G,M)?$ Here $\hat{H}$ denotes Tate cohomology.

I seem to recall this from grad school (I then turned to other things), but I cannot prove it, and I think I might have had it wrong back then.

Comment: Do you have interesting examples of such $M$ in mind?